# Compact a VHD on a linux host

Tags: linux, virtualbox, vhd

On a Linux host (Linux Mint 18), how can I compact a VHD file ?

So far my search always returns solutions with Hyper-V or situations with a Linux guest on a Windows host, but have the inverse: a Windows guest running with VirtualBox on a Linux host.

Comment: AFAIK Hyper-V does not exist for linux hosts. Are you sure you are using Hyper-V? The VHD format is used by other hypervisors as well, for example  VirtualBox and Xen.

Comment: I'm not using Hyper-V but Virtualbox. I tagged it with Hyper-V as the VHD(x) format is most often used in Hyper-V context.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/599905/errors-when-compacting-virtualbox-vhd-image

Comment: I don't know what you have been searching, but "virtualbox compact vhd" has a lot of search results, most of them looking promising.

Comment: Figured it out myself by now :) . I did not search for virtualbox as I assumed it was uncapable of compacting VHDs directly so I looked for alternative tools to do this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kind of feel stupid because I found an answer while trying to circumvent the usage of VHD files on Linux. Cloning the disk to the VDI format (after runing sdelete on the Windows guest) also shrinks it to the smallest size:

```
vboxmanage clonemedium INPUT.VHD OUTPUT.VDI --format VDI --variant standard
```

It also works from VHD to VHD

```
vboxmanage clonemedium INPUT.VHD OUTPUT.VDI --format VDI --variant standard
```

This solutions is not as efficient as "compacting" because you need extra storage to store a second copy of the virtual disk and after the process has finished you need to swap the files.